# Insert query echo success but not updating in mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to fetch a cart array through `foreach` loop. I can fetch array items successfully and when i `echo` them it shows the correct values. But when i apply `insert` query for each item to enter in my database table, It does not insert any thing but it shows success. I have 4 tables named:

1. customers-->serial `primary`,name,email,password,address,phone,city
2. products-->productid `primary`,name,description,image,price
3. orders-->serial `primary`,date,customerid `foreign key`
4. order_detail-->orderid,productid,quantity,price,color,size

order_detail and orders table should be updated when i click on button.
Here is my code. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login_email'])) {
    $email = $_SESSION['login_email'];
    //Insert values in order table. This works correctly!!
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT serial FROM customers WHERE email = '$email'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $cust_id = $row['serial'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $que = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO orders VALUES('', '$date', '$cust_id')");
    }

    // Fetching serial from orders table. This also works correct.
    $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT serial FROM orders WHERE customerid = '$cust_id'");
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $serial = $row1['serial'];
        echo $serial ."\n";
    }
    //Problem comes here. Here i am trying to insert values in order_details
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
        $subtotal = $value['price'] * $value['quantity'];
        $pid = $value['id'];
        $quantity = $value['quantity'];
        $color = $value['color'];
        $size = $value['size'];
    }
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES ($serial, $pid, $quantity, $subtotal, $color, $size)");
    if (true) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo"not success";
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo"not success";` => `mysqli_error($con);` and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: According to your code it will always print "success", regardless, because the condition it needs to pass is, `if(true)`.

Comment: The conditional `if(true)` cannot be anything other than true

Comment: @Danila Hanchar STOP EDITING CODE http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10475915 as you tried in this other rejected edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10475865

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why it isn't inserting the values in `order_details` table. I am not understanding this.

Comment: Replace `echo "not success";` with `echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and tell us what you see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it displays `Error: Unknown column 'blue' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- But when i `var_dump($value)` it displays me the whole array correctly!! i.e `Array
(
    [quantity] => 6
    [id] => 3
    [price] => 7.4
    [size] => L
    [color] => yellow
    [name] =>  
Cool T-shirt
)
Array
(
    [quantity] => 1
    [id] => 4
    [price] => 8.5
    [size] => S
    [color] => yellow
    [name] => HBD T-Shirt
)
Array
(
    [quantity] => 2
    [id] => 4
    [price] => 8.5
    [size] => XL
    [color] => blue
    [name] => HBD T-Shirt
)
Array
(
    [quantity] => 1
    [id] => 3
    [price] => 7.4
    [size] => L
    [color] => blue
    [name] =>  
Cool T-shirt
)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i solved it!! It was because i was not passing color and size value as string.Thanks for teaching me the error reporting technique. I am a learner.

Comment: You're welcome @tabia glad to see it was solved, *cheers* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try this?

```
if( mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES ($serial, $pid, $quantity, $subtotal, $color, $size)") ){
   echo "success";
    } else {
        echo"not success";
    }
```

I Think you better can do the insert in this way:

```
INSERT INTO order_detail (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Comment: it showed me "not success" now :/ But why it is not inserting

Comment: I did not checked your code I only pointed you about the way you were cheknig if the query was successful.

Comment: can you please sort out the problem

Comment: Please If you want help it is important that you debug your PHP for the errors and report them here.

Comment: it gives `Error: Unknown column 'blue' in 'field list'`

Comment: Your field list are the columns in your order_detail Table, it seems you are misplacing the values in your query. I can guess that the value 'blue' has to be posted in the column 'color'!

Comment: i solved the issue !! :) It was because i was not inserting color as string. It should be like this. `"INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES ($serial, $pid, $quantity, $subtotal, '$color', '$size')`.btw thank you for your time